# Assembly Matrix Comparison Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, x86

My goal is to load values in a 5x5 matrix and compare each value and print out the largest number.

After running a debugger I get :

```
0x080480bb <+0>:     mov    esi,DWORD PTR [eax+edi*1]

0x080480be <+3>:     jmp    0x804809d <loop>
```

```
segment .data
    matrix db   1,62,3,44,35, \
            61,52,43,45,55, \
            17,23,37,74,65, \
            13,12,93,94,95, \
            31,21,13,14,25

segment .bss

holder  resb    4

counter resb    4


segment .text

global _start

_start:

    mov eax, matrix
    call big

big:
    mov esi, holder
    mov edi, counter
    mov edi, 0
    jmp switch

loop:
    inc edi
    cmp esi, [eax + edi]
    jg switch
    cmp edi, 25 
    jle loop
    mov eax, [esi]
    sub eax, '0'
    mov eax, 4              
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esi
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80

switch:
    mov esi, [eax + edi]
    jmp loop

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: I've formatted your code for you (in the future, select all your code and then press Ctrl+K or click the `{ }` button). Now, are you using an assembly level debugger? If not, then that's the first step.

Comment: `mov esi, holder` moves the address of `holder` into `esi`. You probably want `mov esi, [holder]` which moves the content of `holder` into esi. Similarly for edi. You're also not handling your byte-sized data properly.

Comment: @user786653 ok well i did the above adjustments ,i still seem to get the same error "Segment Fault" its strange logically it makes sense and should work but Segment Fault doesn't really mean anything to me

Greg thanks i'll remember the tip for next time :)

Comment: i ran the debugger and it states : 
   0x080480bb <+0>:     mov    esi,DWORD PTR [eax+edi*1]
   0x080480be <+3>:     jmp    0x804809d <loop>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some problems in your code. Here's the first one:

```
cmp edi, 25 
jle loop
mov eax, [esi]   <--
sub eax, '0'
mov eax, 4
```

At this point, you've checked the whole matrix and want to write down the largest value found, which is already in esi, so you don't have to dereference to get it. Also, you should be *adding* '0' for numbers between 0 and 9, so the conversion is also wrong. And, one final thing, after converting you're overwriting the value in eax, which is therefore lost.
The real segmentation fault, howewer, happens here,

```
mov esi, [eax + edi]   <--
jmp loop
```

Right after you write the result. The problem is that ecx should contain a pointer to the zero terminated string to write. Instead of that, you put in it the number you want to write, which is undefined behavior (it means everything might happen). Now, eax holds write's return value, so my guess is that an error occurred and eax now contains -1, resulting in a seg. fault.
One simple work-around for that is adding a jmp exit after you write the value.

And, last but not least, (and as @user786653 said), "not handling your byte-sized data properly". What does that mean? Basically, your matrix is an array of bytes, but every time you read from memory you pick up 4 bytes at time. The simplest solution is to declare your matrix as a double words array (dd or dword in place of db) and multiply by 4 the offset (example: mov eax, [ebx + ecx * 4]).

C'mon, don't worry! Assembly is a difficult beast to play with ;)

**EDIT:**
The part which finds the greatest number is correct. You just have to fix the "output" part and the addressing stuff I said before. In my opinion, if you use the hex base for your numbers converting it to a printable string will be much easier (you can multiply by 2^n by shifting left by n places -> shl eax, 5 = eax *= 32)

Comment: small correction: It's `dd` not `dw` to define double words (the latter defines words, woo ancient terminology). (And they'll need to be index by * 4 in places)

Comment: @BlackBear i think my biggest problem right now is retrieving a value from the matrix which is stored in an array and displaying it to the screen :S i cant believe its so much harder to do such a small procedure in assembly

Comment: @Shawnricshawnawic: Search for other posts on this site that ask about assembly/convert/hex/ascii. Also you might want to search, download and include Irvine32.inc for all your console needs. (or look at the source)

Comment: Hey i've made the changes above but the funny thing is i still get segmentation fault , 

these are the changes i've made : 
 1) Changed array type to dd
 2) when converting im adding '0' 
 3) in my switch i wrote right after jmp loop i put a jmp exit :S
which is odd since it still doesnt work guys i could really use your help on this since i feel im close but yet no  cigar

Comment: ^^^ @BlackBear, any advice would help.